# Cannot invoke getRecords(int) on the array type

Tags: java, android, arrays, int

I cannot seem to get past this error no matter what I try - I've tried removing the int values (as it seems I should) however this only leads to more compiler errors.

Any suggestions?

```
 void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    // only one message sent during the beam
    NdefMessage[] msg =  new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        msg[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
        // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
        beamMsg.setText(new String(msg.getRecords(1).getPayload()));
        beamMsg2.setText(new String(msg.getRecords(1).getPayload()));
    }}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error text? For more context

Comment: Cannot invoke getRecords(int) on the array type NdefMessage[] Connect.java line 164 Java Problem
Cannot invoke getRecords(int) on the array type NdefMessage[] Connect.java line 163 Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at the documentation located [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html#getRecords%28%29) it appears your syntax is off.

To reference a specific record index the code should be the following

```
msg.getRecords()[1].getPayload()
```

although there is probably a logic error also and you should be calling `msg[i]` like so

```
msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()
```